# Unknown job: php5-fpm

Tags: php, nginx, debian

I am running a debian 7 server and installed nginx and php-fpm
But when I try to start or restart php5-fpm I get this error:

```
start: Unknown job: php5-fpm
```

The file php5-fpm exists in /etc/init.d/

When I try to execute
    sh /etc/init.d/php5-fpm
It does not return anything to me in my console.

Hope you can help me.

Comment: Can you share whats in the /etc/init.d/php5-fpm script?

Comment: The problem is only that php-fpm does not start with the server. I can do php5-fpm --help

Comment: I don't have the answer yet but if you `sudo su -` and try it it will work. Not sure how `service` works but seems php5-fpm isn't "registered" with `service` only for your user. (At least that's my case.)

Comment: Actually it's a known bug... See here for a workaround and status: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5/+bug/1272788/